# How to add Seven Tab bar item in tab bar without swipe and swipe gesture in ios?

Tags: ios, tabbar

i am new in iOS development.i ask this question once again because i not got answer my question is that how i add a seven tab item in tab bar without more button or i not want to swipe the tab bar.it is possible??? if possible than please give me answer. or any resources for that.

Comment: you can check with this link.http://code4app.net/category/tabbar/2

Comment: #Ramesh Muthe i check it but i want a "TabBar with Expands" project but there page is not found..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITabBarController), You can only see five tabs on screen with **More** button. As per your requirement you can not bypass **More** button. You have to create your custom view (e.g `UIScrollView`) and then add tabs in that.

Below are some good example which will help and guide to get your desire customisable tab bar controller.

1. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/crtabbarcontroller
2. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ciexpandabletabbar
3. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/idscrollabletabbar

Comment: #MehulPatel i make a tab bar with storyboard and it contain seven item. it is ok but when i pressed more button i not want to edit button and navigation controller so,it is possible to remove that edit button and navigation bar from my tab bar????? if possible than give me solution...

Answer (score 0):

Build your own view. Subclass `UIViewController` and add seven buttons to it. And reproduce how `UITabBarController`works.

cf : https://github.com/vincentsaluzzo/VSTabBar

Comment: Please you give me any resources link?